# Search for closest correct word in Postgres full text search

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search, text-search, spelling

I have a search-functionality in my app done with https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html.
I want to add the correction of spelling mistakes, in the fashion of "Did you mean ... ?".

So far I have seen that you can get the similarity of words with https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html. This doesn't exactly match what I want, is I want a recommendation for the correction of a possible flawed input. Just getting the similarity assumes I would already know what correctly spelled word is meant.

Can Postgres do this? An example would be correcting "Borritoh" to "Burrito".

Comment: You can either have text search or similarity search, but not both.

Comment: So the best option is likely to first do text search with the raw input, and then additionally check if it's spelled right, and in case it's not, provide the option to do text search with the correct word? 
In that case I'd likely need a different service that does spelling correction, right?

Comment: Perhaps, but it is nothing you will be able to do with PostgreSQL alone.

Answer (score 1):

> Just getting the similarity assumes I would already know what correctly spelled word is meant.

No, you just need a dictionary of recognized words.  You then order your dictionary of recognized words by similarity or distance with a LIMIT 1.

If you build the trigram index of the GiST flavor, it will support ordering directly:

```
select word from dictionary ORDER BY word <-> 'Borritoh' limit 1
```

However, this will be pretty slow if none of the recognized words are similar.  It might be better to use `%` to put a floor below which it just doesn't make any recommendation (which which will probably be better done with a GIN than GiST index, you should try it both ways).

```
select word from dictionary where word % 'Borritoh' ORDER BY word <-> 'Borritoh' limit 1
```